# How can I find all the DLLs to include in an MFC VS project? 

Tags: windows, dependencies, release

I have statically linked the MFC, but when I give the EXE to anyone an error occurs.

I have used Dependency Walker to find all the external DLLs that I needed. I run the Dependency Walker in Profile mode (F7). Running the application after including all the listed files, gives the following error:

> msvc100.dll not found

After I add this file in the folder, the application starts. But I can't find all the external DLL dependencies this way. Is there's another (better) way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [tutorial on how to redistribute the MFC libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235264%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Did you have a look at that?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. Now I've a better know how about this problem. Indeed the problem remains, because the Dependency Walker doesn't show all the dlls needed.